# How to keep the UI views' sizes the same when the keyboard appears?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-activity, fragment

Please look at the attached screenshot, i have a fragment in the left appears over an exiting activity, but when the keyboard appears you can notice the components in the right activity layout are compressed . how can I design the layout of the activity to only scrolled up NOT compressed when the keyboard appears.

[image]

I've tried `baboo` post   `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`: but I got the following results: [image]

But as you see the screens are cut from the bottom ?!

Comment: post code of your manifest where this activity is defined as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust  android:windowSoftInputMode in the activity in which fragment is present
try using

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in you Manifest